# Creating timed protect event on excel worksheet unprotect

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to use the event of unlocking an Excel worksheet to trigger a timer to relock the worksheet after a specified duration of time. However, I can't find an event for the excel sheet unlock.

What I have found is something similar in this code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "Protectsheets"
End Sub



Sub Protectsheets()
Sheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="Password"
Sheets("Sheet3").Protect Password:="Password"
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no event for unprotecting a sheet. The only thing you can do is instead of Excels built in unprotect use a self made macro which unprotects the sheet then also sets the timer for reprotection. If you hardcode the passwords and don't tell the users they are not able to use the built in unprotect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Peh in that I'm not aware of any unprotect event. There are a number of options still available to you, though. At its simplest, you could just have the timer permanently running and action your code if the `Worksheet.ProtectContents` property is ever `False`; there's also @Peh's suggestion which looks attractive in terms of time to develop. However, another answer that comes to mind is to exploit the fact the Unprotect menu item activates a dialogue window. So you could create a hook that looks for that window.

The WH_CBT hook comes to mind as it won't be triggered too often while the hook is registered. The code below shows how you might implement such a hook. It's probably possible to pick up the "OK" button handle too but I believe it's not visible in the child window enumerations so you might have to do something clever with the IAccessibility interface to find it. I'm not sure you really need it, though.

A few points about the code: firstly, I'm still on 32 bit, so you'd need to adjust the API definitions for 64 bit if that's what you need - there should be plenty of examples on the internet; secondly, I don't believe it's possible to call `Application.OnTimer` within a callback function, so an obvious answer is to use the Windows timer - you'll see a couple of APIs for that too; thirdly, this code traps events from a windows handle, so if someone were to unprotect the sheet via VBA (or other programme), this solution wouldn't pick it up.

So ... in a Module (I've called mine *modHook*), paste the following:

```
Option Explicit

'=======================================================
' HOOK APIs AND CONSTs
'=======================================================
Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx _
    Lib "user32" _
    Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" ( _
    ByVal idHook As Long, _
    ByVal lpfn As Long, _
    ByVal hmod As Long, _
    ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CallNextHookEx _
    Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hHook As Long, _
    ByVal ncode As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Long, _
    lParam As Any) As Long

Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx _
    Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hHook As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetCurrentProcessId _
    Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Declare Function GetCurrentThreadId _
    Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLength _
    Lib "user32" _
    Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" ( _
    ByVal HWnd As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowText _
    Lib "user32" _
    Alias "GetWindowTextA" ( _
    ByVal HWnd As Long, _
    ByVal lpString As String, _
    ByVal cch As Long) As Long

Private Const WH_CBT = 5
Private Const HCBT_DESTROYWND As Long = 4

'=======================================================
' TIMER APIs
'=======================================================
Public Declare Function SetTimer _
    Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal HWnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
    ByVal uElapse As Long, _
    ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function KillTimer _
    Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal HWnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long

'=======================================================
' MODULE-LEVEL VARIABLES
'=======================================================
Private mHookID As Long
Private mTimerID As Long
Private mDuration As Single


Public Function Callback(ByVal lngCode As Long, _
                         ByVal wParam As Long, _
                         ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

    'Your CBT callback function.

    Dim txt As String
    Dim retVal As Long

    'Handle the message if it's a window being destroyed.
    If lngCode = HCBT_DESTROYWND Then
        'Get the name of the window.
        retVal = GetWindowTextLength(wParam)
        If retVal > 0 Then
            txt = String(retVal + 1, Chr$(0))
            retVal = GetWindowText(wParam, txt, Len(txt))
            'If it's the Unprotect window, start the timer.
            If txt = "Unprotect Sheet" & Chr$(0) Then
                mTimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, 5000&, AddressOf TimerProc)
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'Keep the hook chain.
    CallNextHookEx mHookID, lngCode, wParam, lParam

End Function

Public Sub Attach()
    'Attach the CBT hook
    mHookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, _
                               AddressOf Callback, _
                               0, _
                               GetCurrentThreadId)

End Sub

Public Sub Detach()
    Dim retVal As Long

    'De-register the hook - note critical task!
    retVal = UnhookWindowsHookEx(mHookID)
    If retVal = 1 Then mHookID = 0
End Sub
Private Sub TimerProc(ByVal _
                      HWnd As Long, _
                      ByVal uMsg As Long, _
                      ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
                      ByVal dwTimer As Long)

    'Your timer callback.

    'First kill the timer to stop it recurring.
    On Error Resume Next
    KillTimer 0&, mTimerID
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Check if the sheet is unprotected.
    'Note: this is needed in case the user hit
    'cancel in the unprotect window.
    If Not Sheet1.ProtectContents Then
        '--> Your timer handling code goes here.
        MsgBox "Hey, you unprotected Sheet1."
    End If
End Sub
```

You can attach your hook wherever you like. In this example, I've done it in the Workbook_Open event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Attach the hook to your desired sheet.
    If Me.ActiveSheet Is Sheet1 Then modHook.Attach
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    'Remove the hook before closing.
    modHook.Detach
End Sub
```

And if you're only interested in one particular sheet (in this example `Sheet1`), then in the code behind that sheet, place the following. It registers and de-registers the hook as the sheet is activated and deativated:

```
'Use these if you only want the hook for this worksheet.
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    modHook.Attach
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    modHook.Detach
End Sub
```